# I have servers that keep becoming inactive in RHEL Satellite 5.3

Tags: linux, redhat, rhel5, satellite

I have lots of RHEL 5 servers subscribed to a Satellite 5.3 server (I know it's all old, not my choice). After I register servers, many of them seem to fall out and become inactive and require reregistration. This used to affect almost all our servers until I realized the NTP server we were using was way off (also not my choice) but I was able to rectify that and so now this only affects a few dozen. But I can't find a source and there are practically no log entries giving hints as to the problem.

Comment: If you're using Satellite then it's likely you have a paid Red Hat support subscription, open a case with your regional Red Hat support center and get same value from that...

Answer (score 1):

The best way to ensure RHEL clients stay continually connected to an RHN Satellite server is to run the OSAD daemon (`osad`) on each client and `osa-dipatcher` on the Satellite server.

You can install OSAD on the clients by subscribing them to the `rhn-tools` channel and running:

```
yum install osad`
chkconfig osad on
service osad start
```

On the RHN Satellite server, just make sure the osa-dipatcher package is installed and that the service is running.

More simply you can create a cron job on the clients to periodically check in with the Satellite server.  Something like the following would do great:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Check for scheduled actions
perl -le 'sleep rand 9000' && rhn_check >& /dev/null
# send latest system info
perl -le 'sleep rand 9000' && rhn-profile-sync >& /dev/null
```

Lastly, if a client ever stops checking in, just run `rhn_check` manually for troubleshooting purposes.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is a native tool implemented - rhnsd. It does the same - performs "rhn_check" every 240 mins. or whatever is set in /etc/sysconfig/rhn/rhnsd